# Set-Cookie header is not set

Tags: java, servlets, cookies, jersey, response

I want to receive a response from my server with a Set-Cookie header. I'm using Jersey, spring-boot and Spring security on the server side and angular 2 on the client side. I receive the response, but the Set-Cookie header is not set. It's only in the metadata:

> {"statusType":"OK","entity":null,"entityType":null,"metadata":{"Set-Cookie":[{"name":"SomeName","value":"someId","version":1,"path":null,"domain":null,"comment":null,"maxAge":-1,"secure":false}]},"status":200}

But there is no "Set-Cookie" Header:
[image: Header]

That's the code from the response:

```
return Response.ok().cookie(new NewCookie("SomeName", "someId")).build();
```

The method ".header(..)" isn't working as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this

```
public ResponseEntity<?> resourceFunction(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.addCookie(new Cookie("SomeName", "someId"));
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

[image: Snippet from Chrome DevTool]

`ResponseEntity`, `HttpServletResponse` and `Cookie` are imported from `javax.servlet.http.*`

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative:

```
public ResponseEntity<?> resourceFunction() {
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, "SomeName=someId");
    return new ResponseEntity(httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```